How to get current Laravel Filament resource page type (operation) create/edit/view
I need to customize some Laravel Filament v3 Resource Form Fields/Elements by the current page type index/create/edit/view. For example, hide some action Fields on a view page.
Resource PHP file (Bar)
<?php
namespace App\Filament\Resources;

use App\Filament\Resources\BarResource\Pages;
use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
use Filament\Forms\Form;

class BarResource extends \Filament\Resources\Resource
{
    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListBars::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateBar::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditBar::route('/{record:uuid}/edit'),
            'view' => Pages\ViewBar::route('/{record:uuid}/view'),
        ];
    }
    
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                TextInput::make('name')
                    ->hidden(function () {
                        //do something in cases of edit/view states, something like $state
                        /*switch ($state) {
                            case 'view':
                                return true;
                                break;
                        }*/
                    }),
            ]);
    }
}

Any ideas how to implement switching (get current) resource page type in a form?

Great that you solve the problem, and nice to see to achieve this with flexible method.
On the other hand though, there are two ways available by Filament.
First:
->hidden(fn($operation) => $operation == 'view')

or
->visible(fn($operation) => $operation == 'edit')

Read more from the Docs
Second:
->hiddenOn('edit')

or
->visibleOn('create')

Read more from the Doc

 I got an ideas that solves the issue.
Examples below are based on edit context/operation. ⚠️ Keep in mind: also you have to make it with create/view/index contexts. Let's create a public property $crud that determines wich context/operation is backed in a given resource class.
1️⃣ VIA MIDDLE CLASSES

CreateRecord class
\App\Override\Filament\Resources\Pages\CreateRecord

EditRecord class
\App\Override\Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord

ViewRecord class
\App\Override\Filament\Resources\Pages\ViewRecord

ListRecords class
\App\Override\Filament\Resources\Pages\ListRecords


EditRecord child class
app\Override\Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord.php
<?php
namespace App\Override\Filament\Resources\Pages;

use Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord as BaseEditRecord;

class EditRecord extends BaseEditRecord
{
    public string $crud = 'edit';
}

Bar Edit
app\Filament\Resources\BarResource\Pages\EditBar.php
<?php
namespace App\Filament\Resources\BarResource\Pages;

use App\Override\Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord;

class EditBar extends EditRecord
{
    //your edit resource code
}

2️⃣ VIA TRAITS

CreateRecord trait
\App\Traits\Filament\Resources\Pages\CreateRecord

EditRecord trait
\App\Traits\Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord

ViewRecord trait
\App\Traits\Filament\Resources\Pages\ViewRecord

ListRecords trait
\App\Traits\Filament\Resources\Pages\ListRecords


EditRecord trait
app\Traits\Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord.php
<?php

namespace App\Traits\Filament\Resources\Pages;

trait EditRecord
{
    public $crud = 'edit';
}

Bar Edit
app\Filament\Resources\BarResource\Pages\EditBar.php
<?php
namespace App\Filament\Resources\BarResource\Pages;

use Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord;

class EditBar extends EditRecord
{
    //our trait
    use \App\Traits\Filament\Resources\Pages\EditRecord;
    
    //your edit resource code
}

 RESULT 
Bar Resource
app\Filament\Resources\BarResource.php
Now you can switch $form->getLivewire()->crud to get a current form context/operation.
<?php
namespace App\Filament\Resources;

use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;

class BarResource extends Resource
{
    //your code...
    
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        $context = $form->getLivewire()->crud;
        return $form
            ->schema([
                TextInput::make('name')
                    ->hidden(function () use ($context) {
                        switch ($context) {
                            case 'edit':
                                //code for edit
                                break;
                            case 'view':
                                //code for view
                                break;
                        }
                    }),
            ]);
    }
}

